# How to query for the default SpeechRecognizer

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

How to find out the ComponentName of the default system speech recognizer, i.e. the one that is returned when [createSpeechRecognizer(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#createSpeechRecognizer(android.content.Context)) is called? (Actually, I only need to find out which input languages it supports, so if there is an answer only to that, then I'd appreciate it as well.)

The framework solves this by

```
String serviceComponent = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE);
```

(See the [source code of SpeechRecognizer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java).)

However, this solution does not seem to be available to a third party app.

Answer (score 7):

> However, this solution does not seem to be available to a third party app.

I assume you came to such conclusion because `Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE` is not a public API. However, [`Settings.Secure.getString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29) requires name of the row to lookup in secure table for the second argument. So, you can simply provide the actual the name of the row you are looking for: ["voice_recognition_service"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java).

That's, you can use the same code from `SpeechRecognizer` with slight change:

```
String serviceComponent = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
        "voice_recognition_service");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm currently using, but I was thinking there is maybe another (preferred) way.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** (I misread the original question)

SpeechRecognizer isn't the thing doing the speech processing, the Intent you pass to SpeechRecognizer, however, is (via `startListening(Intent intent)`). That intent uses `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` and, AFAIK, can be detected in the old-fashioned way.

To detect defaults, try resolving the Intent that you want the find the default for but with the `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` set.

Untested code:

```
String detectDefaultSpeechRecognizer(Context context) {
  final Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
  // 1: Try to find the default speech intent
  final ResolveInfo defaultResolution = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(speechIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  if (defaultResolution != null) {
    final ActivityInfo activity = defaultResolution.activityInfo;
    if (!activity.name.equals("com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity")) {
      //ResolverActivity was launched so there is no default speech recognizer
      return "";
    }
  }
  // 2: Try to find anything that we can launch speech recognition with. Pick up the first one that can.
  final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(speechIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  if (!resolveInfoList.isEmpty()) {
    speechIntent.setClassName(resolveInfoList.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfoList.get(0).activityInfo.name);
    return resolveInfoList.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
  }
  return "";
}
```

***OLD ANSWER***

Check out GAST, it has a way to check if a language is supported in a speech recognizer.
https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingActivity.java#L70

You could also try to manually check the `<recognition-service>` metadata tag. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html#SERVICE_META_DATA

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this answers my question. I know already how to check which languages a recognizer supports, once I know which recognizer to query for that. What I need is to find out which recognizer has been set to be the default. Metadata does not help here, as this doesn't allow a recognizer to declare that it is the default, only that it is a recognizer.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer to match more of what you mean. SpeechRecognizer isn't what's actually doing the speech recognition, it's just launching the service.

Comment: Isn't your new answer querying for activities? I'm interested in services only.

Comment: Dang! You're right! My bad. Good thing there's `resolveService()` as well that works just the same as `resolveActivity()`. I updated the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find out which input languages the default system speech recognizer supports ([`createSpeechRecognizer (Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#createSpeechRecognizer%28android.content.Context%29)), there is a more straightforward way to do it.

All you need to do is using a [`RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#getVoiceDetailsIntent%28android.content.Context%29) intent that will check the default system speech recognizer languages:

```
Intent intent = RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(getApplicationContext());

        if (intent != null) {
            ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Receiving Supported Speech Recognition Languages broadcast "
                                    + intent);

                    final Bundle extra = getResultExtras(false);

                    if ((getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                            && (extra != null)
                            && (mHandler != null)
                            && ((extra
                                    .containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) || (extra
                                    .containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE)))) {

                        List<String> supportedLanguages = extra
                                .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
                        String prefLang = extra
                                .getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);

                    }
                }

            },

            null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
        }
```

Comment: @Kaarel is not this what you are looking for? A simple way to find out the supported languages of the default system speech recognizer? Please note that all code is in the public API (which is preferable) and easier to maintain

Comment: Thanks. I think `getVoiceDetailsIntent` gives me the _activity_ that implements `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` (see the source code). I need a service instead.